# Trying to get data in Frontend based on fields from custom table on DB

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to get the value based on the field input like email, contactno on the input field in frontend, my getagentdata.php is below,

```
<?php
namespace Webkul\Pos\Controller\Index;

class GetAgentData extends AbstractPos
{

public function execute()
{
    $returnArray             = [];
    $returnArray["success"]  = 1;
    $returnArray["message"]  = "";
    $returnArray["agent"] = [];
    try  {
        if ($this->_coreSession->getIsLoggedin()) {
            $wholeData   = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            $agentId  = $wholeData["agentId"]  ?? 0;
            $searchQuery = $wholeData["searchQuery"] ?? "";
            $searchQuery = trim($searchQuery);
            $agentCollection = $this->_agents->create()->addNameToSelect();

            if ($agentId > 0) {
                $agentCollection->addFieldToFilter("id", $agentId);
            } else {
                $agentCollection->addFieldToSelect("email")
                    ->addFieldToFilter(
                        [
                            ["field"=>"email", "like"=>"%".$searchQuery."%"],
                            ["field"=>"contactno", "like"=>"%".$searchQuery."%"]
                        ]
                    );
            }
            $agentCollection->setOrder("id", "DESC");
            $agentData = [];
            foreach ($agentCollection as $agent) {
                $eachAgentData = [];
                $eachAgentData = $agent->getData();
                $eachAgentData["id"] = (int)$eachAgentData["id"];
                $eachAgentData["firstname"] = $eachAgentData["firstname"];
                $eachAgentData["lastname"] = $eachAgentData["lastname"];
                $eachAgentData["contactno"] = $eachAgentData["contactno"];
                unset($eachAgentData["is_active"]);
                unset($eachAgentData["created_at"]);
                unset($eachAgentData["updated_at"]);
                unset($eachAgentData["password"]);


                $returnArray["agent"][] = $eachAgentData;
                //$eachAgentData->debug();
            }
            $returnArray["success"] = 1;
        } else {
            $returnArray["message"] = __("Session Expired.");
        }
        return $this->getJsonResponse($returnArray);
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        $returnArray["message"] = $e->getMessage();
        return $this->getJsonResponse($returnArray);
    }
}
}
```

But magento2 returns this error.

> {"success":1,"message":"Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in /var/www/sqdelivery/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php on line 423","agent":[]}

if i comment the below else part, Error is not coming

```
else {
            $agentCollection->addFieldToSelect("email")
                ->addFieldToFilter(
                    [
                        ["field"=>"email", "like"=>"%".$searchQuery."%"],
                        ["field"=>"contactno", "like"=>"%".$searchQuery."%"]
                    ]
                );
        }
```

I think problem is on the addFieldToFilter & addFieldToSelect.

Please help me to solve this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try after disable this `setOrder` function.

Comment: @kunj  see the updated question bro.. problem is in addFieldToFilter or addFieldtoSelect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $agentCollection->addFieldToSelect("email") ->addFieldToFilter( "email",["like"=>"%".$searchQuery."%"])
->addFieldToFilter("contactno",["like"=>"%".$searchQuery."%"]);
```

Comment: this also returns the same error bro..

Comment: Ok, try this `echo $agentCollection->getSelect()->__toString();` and run that query in mysql. check that query working or not

Comment: i had get this on echo, *{"success":1,"message":"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{firstname}})), ' ', LTRIM(RTRIM({{lastname}}))) AS `id` FROM `pos_agent` AS `ma' at line 1, query was: SELECT `main_table`.*, CONCAT(LTRIM(RTRIM({{firstname}})), ' ', LTRIM(RTRIM({{lastname}}))) AS `id` FROM `pos_agent` AS `main_table` WHERE ((`email` = '') OR (`contactno` = '')) ORDER BY main_table.id DESC\n","agent":[]}*

Comment: I think you need to correct this code `$agentId  = $wholeData["agentId"]  ?? 0;
            $searchQuery = $wholeData["searchQuery"] ?? "";`

Comment: i had cleared the error. problem in the collection.solved. but now if i echo the agentcollection it return the echo like this " SELECT `main_table`.`email` FROM `pos_agent` AS `main_table` WHERE ((`email` = '') OR (`contactno` = '') OR (`firstname` = '') OR (`lastname` = ''))"

Comment: this query never retrieve any value since in OR condition null values are there..

Comment: have you filtered for `firstname` and `lastname`? if yes please share updated code in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$agentCollection-> addFieldToFilter(
    [
     ["email", "contactno"],
     ["like" => "%{$searchQuery}%"], ["like" => "%{$searchQuery}%"]
    ]
);
```

Comment: it works bro. but returns the "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064"